# How to find the shaded region

Tags: geometry, area

> Find the area of the blue shaded region of the square in the following image:
>
> [image]

---

**[Added by Jack:]**

The area of the triangle in the middle of the square is given by
$$
4.8\times 6=28.8\  (cm^2)
$$

Other than this, it seems difficult to go further with the given information. It seems that one has yet to use the assumption of "square".

How can one solve this problem?

Comment: What else is given?

Comment: Nothing, this is the entire question.

Comment: Where the points of the blue region are located?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you need more information.

Comment: This image was all that was given. Sorry I do not know any other details.

Comment: So is it not possible to solve this with the given information ?

Comment: I think there is enough information, so it's solvable unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Given sides $A=6, B=4.8\rightarrow C=\sqrt{6^2+4.8^2}=7.683749085$, we know little more about this figure than appearance. If appearance counts, it appears that the left side is touched by a diagonal $\frac{2}{3}$ up from the bottom and the top is touched by a diagonal $\frac{2}{3}$ away from the left side. The left shaded area appears to be similar to the defined triangle but I don't know how to prove or disprove it.

Comment: @Oliver Show please your attempts, otherwise this topic would be removed.

Comment: @Oliver, you posted an interesting question, now you should edit it (by pressing on edit) to include what you can notice (can you label sides? can you find area of any triangle with labels or numbers? can you observe the given answers and comment what you understood? etc). Then you can keep this post alive and it will benefit other users. Otherwise, it will be deleted as useless. And yes, in addition to public interest, I also have a personal interest in this. Thank you and Good luck!

Comment: Attention to deleters: please, give OP time to log on (last logged on 15 August 2019) and think about his question, thank you.

Comment: @Zacky and user21820, please, stop editing it. I think unless the OP adds something to his post, it should stay closed (eventually deleted). The OP can take his time and edit it any time he wishes. Thank you all.

Comment: DO NOT VANDALIZE the post in order to vote to close/delete it!

Comment: @farruhota: It is Zacky and Jack who are vandalizing the post in order to preserve it by putting words into the asker's mouth. I agree with you that it should stay closed and eventually deleted, but as you can see it is Zacky and Jack who are trying to reopen it (again). Also, the asker has visited the site already for many days and still have not added anything to his post. Let the asker do it!

Comment: Rules are rules. If an asker does not show any effort or interest to answer his own question, the question must be downvoted, closed and sooner or later deleted. Others must not act on behalf of the asker. These rules maintain the order and make the MSE a real platform of exchange of ideas. If these rules are deliberately violated after warnings, then the MSE moderators can take measures. Thank you for understanding.

Comment: @farruhota: " If an asker does not show any effort or interest to answer his own question, the question *must* be downvoted, closed and sooner or later deleted. " This is by no means a rule. Such comment is extremely misleading. There is no such thing in [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help). (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Please check this answer in meta: ["Do not roll back improvements to a question unless they clearly make it worse or conflict with the question's intent.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30041/9464)". And also the [recent edit of a post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3143084/revisions) after a decent answer was posted.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: Did you find something wrong in your answer so that you deleted it?

Comment: @Jack, having seen so many closed questions due to lack of context and effort, it almost became an unwritten rule. But in the [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/30041/9464) you provided I particularly liked and support the idea "generating good content for readers is more important than training askers". Indeed, several people created a good content by answering the question. So it is better to add a short context in OP and make it benefit all users rather than to close and delete it just because there was no initial effort. Peace and respect!

Answer (score 12):

Draw the red line as shown:

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

Note:
$$\begin{cases}1=2+3\\
4=3+6\end{cases} \Rightarrow 1+6=2+4 \Rightarrow S=\frac12 \cdot 4.8\cdot 6=14.4.$$
To prove $4=3+6$, note that the triangles $3+5+6$ and $4+5$ are congruent, because corresponding one side and three angles are equal.

Comment: Excellent, well done!

Comment: I made the edit before realizing that "minus" signs were intended to be dashes. Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the following picture.

[image]

Comment: rl/6 how did you get that?

Comment: @Oliver The triangles on the left and bottom are similar.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Consider a unit square with the bottom left corner at the origin and the point $(t,1)$.

The oblique from the bottom left corner has equation

$$y=\frac{x}{t}$$

and the other oblique is perpendicular, from the bottom right corner, hence

$$y=-t(x-1).$$

The intersection point is

$$\left(\frac{t^2}{t^2+1},\frac{t}{t^2+1}\right).$$

To determine $t$, we express the value of the ratio of the known sides,

$$\frac{4.8}{6}=\frac{\left\|\left(\dfrac{t^2}{t^2+1},\dfrac{t}{t^2+1}\right)-(t,1)\right\|}{\left\|\left(\dfrac{t^2}{t^2+1},\dfrac{t}{t^2+1}\right)-(1,0)\right\|}.$$

All the rest will follow.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start with a square $ABCD$ and construct on the sides $AB$, $BC$, $CD$, $DA$ points $E,F,G,H$ so that $AE=BF=CG=DH$:

[image: A square divided into pieces]

Let $X$ be the intersection $X=AG\cap BH$. Similar points $Y,Z,W$ obtained by rotation around the center of the square were also drawn. This realizes the situation from the given problem. We want to become independent of the given values for $XG$ and $XB$, and show in general:

> The blue area together is equal to the area of triangle $\Delta BXG$.

(To have some symmetry, and some common part with $\Delta BXG$ some green triangles have been also drawn.)

(Note that because of $DH=CG$ the area of the blue triangle $\Delta DHB$ is equal to the area of the blue triangle in the OP, $\Delta BGC$.)

---

**Proof:**
$$
\begin{aligned}
2\operatorname{Area}(\Delta BXG) 
&=
2\operatorname{Area}(\Delta YXW) 
+
2\operatorname{Area}(\Delta YWB) 
+
2\operatorname{Area}(\Delta GWB) 
\\
&=
\operatorname{Area}(\square XYZW) 
+
YB\cdot XW
+
WG\cdot XB
\\
&=
\operatorname{Area}(\square XYZW) 
+
AX\cdot XY
+
YE\cdot XB
\\
&=
\operatorname{Area}(\square XYZW) 
+
2\operatorname{Area}(\Delta AXE)
+
2\operatorname{Area}(\Delta XEB)
\\
&=\text{"Blue area  plus green area"}
\\
&=
2\operatorname{Area}(AXH) +
2\operatorname{Area}(DHB) 
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and the result follows.

$\square$

---

I tried to show "the square in the middle", and use in the proof the full symmetry.

---

**Later edit:**
Here is a further picture that illustrates the way to split the triangle $\Delta BXG$ in three triangles, that can be pasted elsewhere with equivalent area:

[[image: Split of the triangle <span class=]$\Delta BXG$ in three parts, one part is half of a square, two other parts add to a side triangle.">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z2vC.png)